# In Ecto, preloading an aggregate query

Tags: elixir, ecto

Lets say I have tables of `posts`, `comments` and `votes`.

The `votes` table has a `direction` column which is either 1, 0 or -1.

I want to query all the posts and also the **count** of comments, and the **sum** of `votes.direction` for each post.

Is this achievable as sub-queries in Ecto, ideally using composable queries on the `Post` model?

Currently what I have is:

```
def count_comments(query) do
  from p in query,
    left_join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
    select: {p, count(c.id)},
    group_by: p.id
end

def get_score(query) do
  from l in query,
    left_join: v in assoc(p, :votes),
    select: {p, sum(v.direction)},
    group_by: p.id
end
```

But I can't compose both these queries as I get this error:

> (Ecto.Query.CompileError) only one select expression is allowed in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what your code fails on, but it could be likely accomplished with:

```
from p in Post,
  left_join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
  left_join: v in assoc(p, :votes),
  group_by: p.id,
  select: {p, count(c.id), sum(v.direction)}
```

[Query compisition](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-composition) is allowed for “not terminated” queries only, that said, for the queries, having no `select` clause (untested, might slightly differ on your structure):

```
with_comments =
  from p in Post,
  left_join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
  group_by: p.id

with_score_and_comments = 
  from [p, c] in with_comments,
  left_join: v in assoc(p, :votes),
  group_by: p.id

result =
  from [p, c, v] in with_score_and_comments,
  select: {p, count(c.id), sum(v.direction)}
```

Comment: That's seems to work. Kind of a seperate question but what's the easiest way to preload a related model for this query. E.g. say the post has a user, how can I ensure the user is loaded in the Post?

Comment: `Ecto` has a good documentation btw https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/search.html?q=preload